# live edit text ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have textarea and inserting the data to database using ajax however I want to be able to edit the text area live, just like facebook does when you edit comments. So far I have got the data inserted to database but I couldn't get the textarea disappear and show the inserted text. Can someone give me hint?

html

```
<textarea row="5" col="20" id="md">
<button href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="mdmsg();">Save</button>
```

js

```
function mdmsg() {
    var md = $("#md").val();
    if (md == "") {
        $("#errormsg").fadeIn('slow').html('<div class="errorreg">enter some text.</div>');
    } else {
        var dataString = 'md=' + md;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test?targ=mdmsg",
            data: dataString,
            success: function (response) {
                $('#md').html(response);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

php

```
if(isset($_GET["targ"]) == "mdmsg")             
{ 
    $cont = $_POST['md'];
    $upd = $db->prepare("update users set bio = ? where user_name  = ?");
    echo $db->error;
    $upd->bind_param('ss', $cont, $username->username);
    $upd->execute();
    echo "success";
    $hg = $db->prepare("select `bio` from users where user_name = ?");
    echo $db->error;
    $hg->bind_param('s', $username->username);
    $hg->execute();
    $res = $hg->get_result();
    while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
    {
        echo "<div id='dvv'>".$row['bio']."</div>";//I want this row to show up on the textarea.
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried replacing `var dataString = 'md=' + md;` with `var dataString = 'md:' + md;`?

Comment: @13ruce1337 what that has to do with what I want? I already said the data is being inserted to database, I just want to hide the textarea once the success is called and show the inserted row.

Comment: looking at the network tab on your developer console do you see the `<div id='dvv'></div>` get returned?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this **[X-editable](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/)** :

if you need help using it post a comment

Comment: I looked it up and it seems too much code, I don't know if you post a code how to use it I would like it.